# open cv buffer size do not match error

Tags: c++, opencv

Working with Open CV using web cam i am getting buffer size do not match error and a blank screen is displayed is displayed.My OS is windows 8.1 and web am is the built in laptop.The web cam is working since its light is glowing.I google for it and got the answer to use another camera but i don't have another so is there any way to solve the issue.Is it a driver problem or something else.
i am using the following method for getting video

```
 CvCapture* a=cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
```

and using the following method for getting each frame:

```
i=cvQueryFrame(a);
```

where 'i' is pointer of class IplImage.
It worked fine on another pc through external web cam having windows 7.
I am working on Code Blocks.

Comment: You tagged c++ and you are on windows 8.1 why would you use the C interface? please consider using C++ interface of OpenCV  (cv::VideoCapture) in your case

Comment: Humam Helfawi can you please describe me how to do that i am new to open cv

Answer (score 0):

First you may consider using the C++ interface of OpenCV:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
int main(){
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat frame;
    while(cap.read(frame){
         cv:: imshow("Frame", frame);
         if( waitKey(1) == 27 ) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

About the problem that the Camera is working on a machine and not on other machine. You should first check that you have the write number for the camera (eg. 0 in the code I provide)

Comment: My version of open cv does not contains opencv.hpp it has cv.h highgui.h and many other but not opencv.hpp

Comment: I think my version of opencv is old since there is no folder opencv2 it has only opencv folder

Comment: the camera on other machine is different and i had sold that machine.

Comment: Getting same message again the problem is different